# JavaScript Minification & Concatenation Best Practices?

Tags: javascript, optimization, requirejs, minify, uglifyjs

If you are building a 10 page site and using uglifyJS to minify and concatenate all the javascript code to a single file, what is the best practice for optimizing code globally across the site?

Let's say for arguments sake all pages have shared code and have some unique code. Do you include all the code into the single minified javascript file and include code that won't be used on every page? Or should you create an additional minified javascript file for every page with the unique code?

I know the best choice is probably unique to every site but if there is a general rule of thumb that applies, I am curious to know what the best approach would be.

Comment: Depends on your website, if javascript query isn't your problem,you can try minified all the file in one, but consider to different page, you can minify js file seperately.